# css animation translate3d breaks :before animation

Tags: css, animation

I have a following problem, i have put animation on div element to slide up nicely when opened (its a modal box):

```
@keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        transform:translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.modal.sign {
    top:10%;
    width:650px;
    left:calc(50% - 325px);
    animation: 1s slideup ease;
}
```

then i have put animation on :before of that element:

```
@keyframes alpha {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

.modal.sign[data-show="true"]:before {
    background:rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.2);
    animation: 1s alpha ease;
}
```

Now, when modal is opened only div element is being animated, while :before just show up when animation is complete, what i can tell is that if i change `translate` to `top` it works properly, why is that translate doesnt work? is there a possible fix that can be done?

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/94cyjay6/)

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 second delay to the alpha animation

```
animation: 1s 1s alpha ease;
```

Then it will start once the slideup animation has finished.

```css
@keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        //top:calc(10% + 20px);
        transform:translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        //top:10%;
        transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes alpha {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

.demo {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:crimson;
    position:fixed;
    top:10%;
    left:calc(50% - 150px);
    animation: 1s slideup ease;
}

.demo2 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.2);
    content:'';
    display:block;
    animation: 1s alpha ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo2"></div>
```

Comment: its all good and well but it doesn't solve the problem, i want these animations to run simultaneously, otherwise it looks rather bad

Comment: I changed the code. I'm afraid the only solution is to introduce another div